# How can I style the selection box around an input control in a browser?

Tags: css

On a website I'm making I've styled the input controls to make them look a little more pleasant - including use of:

```
border-radius: 15px 15px;
```

to make the controls have more rounded corners.

This works great, but the problem is that when the user selects the control in question, a selection style seems to appear around the outside of it to show its the active control.  This selection style/border doesn't seem to follow the border-radius set up for the control in general.  I'm guessing this is kind of like a link:hover situation, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

How do I handle the style of a control when it's selected specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is, it's the :focus pseudo selector: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmednuaman/SMfQg/